# Copying selected character from string

Tags: c++, c

My input string is

`\\?\bac#dos&ven_bb&prod_open-v&rev_5001#1&7f6ac24&0&353020304346333030363338#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}`

Required output is

`bac\dos&ven_bb&prod_open-v&rev_5001\1&7f6ac24&0&353020304346333030363338_0`

I have written a following code but is not working...need help is figuring out the problem. 
Forgive my ignorance :) Also let me know if there is any better and efficient way to do it.

The rule for the output string is

In the second string i am removing all the "\" and "?" .And where is see the "#" i replace it with "\". and the second string is only till you see the charater "{" but does not include "#" at the end of it.

THanks

```
int main() 
{
    char s[] = "\\?\bac#dos&ven_bb&prod_open-v&rev_5001#1&7f6ac24&0&353020304346333030363338#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}";
    char s1[] = {0};
    printf("OUtput string is : ");
    for(int i = 0; s[i] != '{'; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] != '\\' && s[i] != '?')
        {
            int j = 0;
            if(s[i] == '#')
            {
                s1[j] = '\\';
                continue;
            }

            s1[j] = s[i];
            j++;
        }

    }

    for(int i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        cout<<s1[i];    
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: That is _not_ C++ code... despite you using cout.

Comment: I knw its more of C. But if C++ has any standard lib which will make life easy i can use it.

Comment: For starters you should declare and initialize the variable j before the loop, initialize s1 with a proper size and append a \0 in s1 at the end of the loop

Comment: Without some sort of specification of the mapping between the two strings, we really can't tell you anything.  What are the rules which led to the second string, given the first?

Comment: In the second string i am removing all the "\\" and "?" and replacing the "#" with "\". and the second string is only the you see the charater "{"

Comment: Win32 Device names by any chance? I believe that this "transformation" is not the documented way and differs from version to version. In particular, it differs between XP and Vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the fixed scope of `j`. In your version you were always assigning to `s1[0]`.

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; s[i] != '{'; i++)
{
    if(s[i] != '\\' && s[i] != '?')
    {
        // int j = 0;
        if(s[i] == '#')
        {
            s1[j] = '\\';
        }
        else
        {
            s1[j] = s[i];
        }
        j++;
    } 
}
```

The other thing is to allocate enough space for the new string. Since you haven't specified the size `char s1[] = {0};` declares an array of size 1. You need to do something like:

```
char s1[sizeof(s)] = { 0 }; // the size of the old array, since we don't know how long the new one will be
```

But since you tagged the Q C++, take advantage of of dynamically resizable `std::string`.

```
std::string s = ".......";
std::string s1;

for(int i = 0; s[i] != '{'; i++)
{
    if(s[i] != '\\' && s[i] != '?')
    {
        if(s[i] == '#')
            s1 += '\\';
        else
            s1 += s[i];
    } 
}
```

Comment: @jrock note that in your first code sample you incorrectly increment j even when encountering '\\' or '?'

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking into using the `std::string::replace()` function. There is plenty of online documentation on this. Take a look at some of the other functions that `std::string` has to offer as they might be of use too. If you are using c++, the use of `std::string` is usually preferable to tinkering with `char` arrays and indices.

Answer (score 0):

Your s1 buffer needs to be increased, as it stands now there is no room for the new string.

E.g.

```
char* s1 = calloc(strlen(s)+1,sizeof(char)); // same size should be enough, free(s1) later
```

the calloc ensures that it is `\0` terminated, in your code you forgotten to add the `\0` so the printout act erratically.

Comment: I get a error when i use malloc or calloc ' error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *''

Comment: Can someone edit my code and provide the working one? I am finding it difficult :(